# AS2 - buttons sometimes, cant be clickable, unless you move the pointer slightly

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2

- I'm using AS2(I know, I know...) to create simple games,

  - however, the buttons I made, randomly stop working (randomly every time I run the game)
  - What it does is basically you click the button once, it does its job, and you can't click it again, unless you move a pointer slightly (it does that will all the buttons).
  - I also have a keyboard short-cuts that does the same function as the buttons, and the keyboard hot-keys are working normaly

and I'm using this script..

```
on(release){ DoSomething(); }
```

Like I said, the bug is totally random, and have no idea how to fix it :(

fix: can't answer because I'm a newb user for 8 hours:

> soo.. i guess it had something to do with focus,  becaus i manualy set
>   focus on different items, and for some reason that screws up the
>   buttons... what I tried tho, is select the button, and in the
>   properties under Tracking options, select the option Track as Menu
>   Item, and that fixed it (i think :D)

Answer (score 2):

Its been a while since i have used actionscript2 but buttons i beleive if you enter the object has 3 options on the timeline bar there and one is what button looks like when hooverd, pressed and you can also select what is actually being pressed(put an alpha rectangle over your object and make it as big as you want your hitarea to be

Answer (score 0):

soo.. i guess it had something to do with focus, becaus i manualy set focus on different items, and for some reason that screws up the buttons... what I tried tho, is

- select the button, and in the properties under Tracking options, select the option Track as Menu Item, and that fixed it (i think :D)